# How to get month name of last 5 months from current month in a dropdown

Tags: jsp, date, calendar

I have a requirement to display dropdown of Names of Current Month and last 5 months. when user selects on any month, it should call the controller method and pass the month value like If user selects February 2014, then i should get 2014-02-28 in the controller. 
Someone please guide me how to move forward. I am using spring portlet mvc framework.  I know how to get current month name :

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM"); 
String s = formatter.format(new Date());
```

But how to populate a dropdown with all last 5 months name along with the current month and in format August 2014.

Answer (score 0):

[`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is your friend:

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

String[] thisAndLastFiveMonths = new String[6];
for (int i = 0; i < thisAndLastFiveMonths.length; i++) {
    thisAndLastFiveMonths[i] = formatter.format(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
}
```

Comment: It is throwing exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'

Comment: Works on my end (Java 7).

Comment: Seems 'Y' was only added in Java 7. If you're at earlier version, try lowercase 'y' instead.

Comment: lowercase 'y' worked. Thanks. But when user selecting any month e.g. february, i m not able to get date as '2014-02-28'. Getting String 'February 2014'. Any guidance?

Comment: To get a date formatted in a specific way, have a look at format specifiers that SimpleDateFormat uses, described in its Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html . To get a specific date of a month, etc, have a look at the java.util.Calendar javadoc (linked in my answer).